# Why does light travel in a straight line and not rotate with us due to gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light, geodesics

I read somewhere that light is affected by gravity, so then why doesn't like us it move along with the earth?

Comment: I don't follow your logic; how does one logically go from "affected by gravity" to "move along with the earth"?

Comment: The reason is the speed I think. Photons travel damn fast, they can't be attracted by the earth... Only a black hole can though.... PS: Im not a physicist lol

Comment: Its path is definitely affected by the presence of the sun, but the Sun's mass is not enough to make light go around like the Earth does

Comment: Possibly the question relates to GR where a massive body like a satellite  rotates around the earth following a geodesic in curved space-time and the question is why light doesn't do this in the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate  of [Is light affected by gravity? Why?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54701)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geometry of the path that light follows definitely changes in the presence of massive objects, e.g. the Sun. [Eddington's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) experiment indeed showed that for the Sun, concluding that the light bends [$\sim 1$ arcseconds](https://www.wired.com/2009/05/dayintech_0529/) when it goes near. This in contrast with the earth that goes a full $360^\circ$ around the sun.

It is possible to make light go around a full revolution, but for that you would need to shrink the Sun to a radius of [$R_s \sim 3$ km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius), and in this case, the light will move in an orbit of radius [$3R_s/2\sim 5$ km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere). Compare this with the actual size of the Sun [$\sim 7\times 10^{5}$ km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_radius), and the size of Earth's orbit [$\sim 1.5\times 10^{8}$ km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth's_orbit)!

Comment: caverac, the equation holds only for black holes. For the sun this equation is not useable. As long as a photon could escape a body it would not be possible that it would revolve around this body. The gravitational potential does not depends of the mass density

Comment: @HolgerFiedler My point is that you would need to create a black hole out of the sun to have photon sphere

Answer (score 0):

The effect of the Earth's gravity on light is way too tiny to care for most purposes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens

Using a classical calculation to get the size of things without getting too fancy, the orbital speed (for a circular orbit) at the surface of the Earth is about $9 \frac{km}{s}$.  The speed of light is about 33 thousand times faster than that.

The the relationship between the mass of the planet and the orbital speed goes like $M \sim v^2$.  So in order for the orbital speed to be 33 thousand times as fast, the Earth would have to be about 1 billion times as massive.

Comment: I think that you should explain this more in detail. Not just refer to  a link.